# How to get Git repo url from my server and push directly to it from local dev. terminal?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have cloned my private repo from Github to my server via SSH including SSH keys. From my development terminal, I use origin to push to the repo on Github. From my server (logged in via Putty) I pull my master branch.

I was wondering if it is possible to directly push my master branch from local development terminal to my server, I was thinking I just need my URL like the GitHub URL user@github..../repo (origin), etc.

**Is this possible and if so, how to determine the right URL?** I get stuck on command (of course it returns Github)

```
git config --get remote.origin.url
```

Comment: "...to my server vis..." you mean, your own *git-server*? Try it with `git remote -v` to show all remotes fetch/push URL.

Comment: There is no place to get the URL from. You need to construct it. As you can connect to the server with `PuTTY` you have SSH access. So use SSH URL. Combine host, port, username (say, "ole") and the full path to the remote directory at the server; run `pwd` at the server to get the full path, will be something like `/home/ole/project`. To verify the URL first run `ssh host ls /home/ole/project`. When it works construct the URL: `ssh://ole@server_host/home/ole/project` and try it with `git`.

Comment: Thank you @phd, you gave the answer that gave me my solution! I have no clue why your answer is not showing up for me to accept as the 'winning' one.

Comment: Because it's a comment, not an answer. Let's me convert it to an answer…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no place to get the URL from. You need to construct it.

As you can connect to the server with PuTTY you have SSH access. So use SSH URL. Combine host, port, username (say, "ole") and the full path to the remote directory at the server.

Run `pwd` at the server to get the full path, it will be something like `/home/ole/project`. To verify the URL first run `ssh host ls /home/ole/project`. When it works construct the URL: `ssh://ole@server_host/home/ole/project` and try it with `git clone`.

Comment: Thank you, you pointed me in the right direction! Able to deploy my code not having to leave VScode :)

Comment: @Ole Glad to be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning to ignore the phase of pushing to Github? If so then no, you have to push first to Github or any git server then only you can pull somewhere else.

Also, As you said the SSH keys are only added to the server, you need to add your local terminal too to push from local machine to Github.

Comment: I'm planning on keeping Github as my main 'hub' for repos. So not ignoring it. Already able to push and pull all directions, and that works. As via VScode I can push and pull to Github, I think it asked me to login at some point. Would like to be able to use VS code also to access my webserver and push (deploy).

I'm new to Git, and looking for a workflow. Happy to follow the common practicces, but hard to find information other than how to communicate with github/local dev.

Comment: There are lots of documentation in GitHub and git in general. Also, can you add more clarification to the question and what behavior you are desiring?